# How to know the size of callbacks in ASP.NET AJAX?

Tags: asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I want to know the size of the callbacks that ASP.NET AJAX are doing. I'm using the ASP.NET Control Toolkit too. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use firefox and [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) for this (look at the 'net' panel in firebug)

Answer (score 1):

[Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829) (Firefox) or [Fiddler 2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) (IE) might be useful - they both show all headers including content size.